# How to call Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree from a background service

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, android-activity, service

I am displaying my Layout from a Sticky Background Service as an app that draws outside of an activity.

I need the user to pick a folder so I call this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

I need to get the selected directory using:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
```

But the service class I am calling the intent from does not override that function since it does not exist outside of an Activity instance.

How can I receive the result in my background service and pass a `requestCode` with the intent?

Comment: Have you try to use  `MessagingCenter` to pass it? You could check the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I ended up just sending a broadcast to my activity, having it run the intent. Get the result in the callback. Then relay it back to the service with another broadcast. Not an ideal solution, but the fastest one I could make.